# How do I iterate through an ArrayList and then write to file using Iterator's next method?

Tags: java

This is the prompt:

> -Get an Iterator from the ArrayList and assign to a local
>    variable.
>
> -Traverse the ArrayList using the Iterator and write the toString of each
>    CreditCardNumber returned by the Iterator's next method to the output file.
>    (You don't need to write any labels this time.)

And this is what I have so far. I'm having trouble with the writing to the file:

```
    public static void writeArr(ArrayList<CreditCardNumber> temp) {
    FileOutputStream outFile = null;
    try {
        outFile = new FileOutputStream("/Users/raska/Desktop/prog6.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    } // end catch
    Iterator<CreditCardNumber> iter = temp.iterator();
    PrintWriter prtWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile, true);

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        CreditCardNumber obj = iter.next();
        prtWriter.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Here is my user input into the ArrayList:

```
    public static ArrayList<CreditCardNumber> userInputArrList() {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
    int arrLength = scanner.nextInt();
    if (arrLength < 1) {
        arrLength = 1;
    }
    ArrayList<CreditCardNumber> aList = new ArrayList<CreditCardNumber>(arrLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength;) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits) for element #" + i);
            String issuerId = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter an account # (9 digits) for element #" + i);
            String accountNum = scanner.next();
            CreditCardNumber obj = new CreditCardNumber(issuerId, accountNum);
            obj.changeId(issuerId);
            aList.add(obj);
            i++;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString()); // don't throw just
                                                // print
        }
    }
    return aList;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: the Traversing part and basically writing to the file. I don't have any idea of how the implementation is supposed to look.

Comment: Do you understand loops?  If not, please study the Java tutorials on loops.

Comment: You can use a simple `while` loop to achieve your need

Comment: @user7 I made an edit to my post. Does that seem like the correct implementation.

Comment: Yes. You are in the right direction. Instead of printing to the console, print use `prtWriter.println`

Comment: I just tried that, yet it still does not print anything to the file.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate the issue if I provide a non-empty list, are you sure your list is populated?

Comment: @D.B. I just provided documentation for my ArrayList population method.

Comment: Still can't recreate the issue. You should work on providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just `close()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never `close()` the `PrintWriter` or `FileOutputStream`.

At the end of the method, do this:

```
try {
    prtWriter.close();
catch (IOException e) {
    // Do some error reporting.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A better way is to use Java's try-with resource statement:

```
public static void writeArr(ArrayList<CreditCardNumber> temp) {
    try (FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("/Users/raska/Desktop/prog6.txt")) {

        Iterator<CreditCardNumber> iter = temp.iterator();
        PrintWriter prtWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile, true);

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            CreditCardNumber obj = iter.next();
            prtWriter.println(obj);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate over the Array using iterator using following example. There are tons others available on web.

```
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
        CreditCardNumber obj = iter.next();
        System.out.println(obj.toString()); -> line causing problem...you need to write to printWriter...using system.out simple outputs to the console
    }
```

Correct code:

```
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
        CreditCardNumber obj = iter.next();
         prtWriter.write(obj.toString()); //hopefully you have overridden toString() in you CreditCardNumber class       
    }
```

Comment: some people cannot provde solutions..only downvote without reason